# split a large file based on elements in another file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I would like to split a large file based on elements in another file. Here is an example data for the first file:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3   
A,10,50  
B,10,05  
C,20,30  
B,20,03  
A,30,100  
C,30,111  
D,40,120
```

The second file is:

```
A  
B  
C
```

I would like to save subset of file1 with first column takes value "A" to A.txt; and "B" to B.txt, and so on.

Before I am using

```
awk '$1=="A"' file1.txt > A.txt
```

but now I have to deal with 100+ different names in the second file, looking for a better way to get the job done.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

The basic elements of your case have been discussed many times on this site e.g.

- [Extract data from a file and place in different files based on1 column value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114061/extract-data-from-a-file-and-place-in-different-files-based-on1-column-value)
- [How to select lines in a file that contain a number from a list of numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256164/how-to-select-lines-in-a-file-that-contain-a-number-from-a-list-of-numbers)

Putting them together,

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++; next} $1 in a {print > $1 ".txt"}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: another option is using `grep -Fwf second_file first_file | awk '{ print >$1".txt"}'` ( assuming names in second_file only can appear in first column of first_file)